# Issue uploading Images into WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

When trying to upload images into WordPress, I keep getting this error:

```
413 Request Entity Too Large

nginx
```

I checked `PHP.ini` file to make sure I have the proper upload-able amount and I have `32mb`

I have a dedicated server with Media Temple and have never had this issue before.  Hope someone could shed some light?

The file sizes I am uploading are about `1 - 3 mb`.  Anything less than `1mb` seems to go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a php.ini issue.  The error is coming from the web server nginx.

Add this line somewhere in your nginx server block (change 5M to whatever you need):

```
    client_max_body_size 5M;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your php.ini file and then restart the server. Restarting the server is key.

```
memory_limit 20MB
post_max_size 20MB
upload_max_filesize 20MB
max_execution_time 600
```